# CSS/Javascript to move background image up and reveal another image on click

Tags: css

I have a background image in a div that displays a US flag to represent English language. When the user clicks on the US flag, I want the flag to move up and display the Japanese flag below it so that the user can then switch languages when they click on either the US or Japanese flag.

Comment: Your ideas sound nice, any code?

Comment: A list of requirements does not a question make. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this, however, is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/5fmjkkcf/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="chooseLanguage">
        <img style="z-index:100;" class="flags" src="http://static.buildasign.com/UPLOAD/images/listings/PID970_United_States_Flag.jpg" />
        <img class="flags" src="http://worldwide.bose.com/electroforce/assets/images/learning_center/Japan_Flag.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:grey;
}
#chooseLanguage {
    margin-top:50px;
    position:relative;
}
.flags {
    height:30px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".flags").click(function () {
    flagHeight = $(this).height();
    $(".flags").removeAttr('style');
    $(this).css({
        top: -flagHeight + "px"
    });
});
```